# Why batch script run in loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My Batch code run in loop. and I don't know why

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Stop Service Adobe
:Adobestop
sc stop AdobeARMservice

REM Start Service Adobe
:Adobestart
sc start AdobeARMservice

REM Enable Fire wall rule Base1
:EnableBase1
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Base1" new enable=yes

REM Disable Fire wall rule Base1
:DisableBase1
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Base1" new enable=no

REM Step 1. disable fire wall rule Base1.
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=Base1 | find /I "Enabled" | find "Yes"    
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 1 (
goto :DisableBase1
) 

REM Step 2. Stop Adobe Service.
sc query AdobeARMservice | find /I "STATE" | find "RUNNING"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 1 (
goto :Adobestop
) 

REM Step 3. Start Adobe Service.
sc query AdobeARMservice | find /I "STATE" | find "STOPPED"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 1 (
goto :Adobestart
) 

REM Step 4. Enable fire wall rule Base1.
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=Base1 | find /I "Enabled" | find "No" 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 1 (
goto :EnableBase1
)
```

Comment: I don't see any labels defined, other than the code pointing to a label.  Also, this is DOS Batch file not PowerShell code.

Answer (score 0):

%ERRORLEVEL% will be 0 if the command completes successfully. Change all of your

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 1 (
```

to

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
```

Perhaps someone was testing the error checking and didn't revert the 1's to 0's.

Comment: There are lots of people on this site that will help, but you have provided no details. 1. What is it that you want it to do? 2. Are you running it locally or in a schedule? 3. Are there any error messages? 4. How far does it get before it repeats? 5. Your design is flawed in that SC does not wait for the command to finish. So you are queing a stop command for AdobeARMservice... not waiting for it to stop and immediately falling through to start the AdobeARMservice. Perhaps you intended to have a GOTO in there or maybe you should have used NET STOP and NET START, which would wait.